# How to generate different random cmd_vel messages?

Tags: ros, navigation, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to have two (or several) robots receiving a random cmd_vel message. I was expecting that each robot would present a different velocity (I'm using Gazebo) but instead what I get is that every robot has the same velocity (however random, it is still the same for each one)

publisher pubvel  is below as well as my launch file where I launch both the robot model and the publisher within the same namespace. One namespace for each robot.

```
    #include "ros/ros.h"
    #include "std_msgs/String.h"
    #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    // Initialize the ROS system and become a node .
    
      ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_velocity");
    
      ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    // Create a publisher object .
      ros::Publisher publisher = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1000);
    
    // Loop at 2Hz until the node i s shut down.
      ros::Rate rate(2); 

    while (ros::ok())
      {
       //srand(time(0));
    
            geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    
            msg.linear.x=double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);
            msg.angular.z=double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX)-1;
            publisher.publish(msg);
    
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"<<" linear="<<msg.linear.x<<" angular=" <<msg.angular.z);
    
            rate.sleep();
      }  
      return 0;
}
```

```
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />

<include file="$(find random_vel)/launch_files/one_robot.launch" >

    <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 0 -y 2 -z 0" />

    <arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot1" />

    <arg name="namespace_arg" value="robot1"/>

</include>

<node pkg="random_vel" type="pubvel" name="pubvel" output="screen" />
```

```
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />

<include file="$(find random_vel)/launch_files/one_robot.launch" >

<arg name="init_pose" value="-x 0 -y -2 -z 0" />

<arg name="robot_name"  value="Robot2" />

<arg name="namespace_arg" value="robot2"/>

</include>
```

Thank you very much in advance,

Hugo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240844/how-to-generate-different-random-cmd_vel-messages?/) by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-08-01**:
Run `rostopic list` to see what topics are being published/subscribed to. Then `rostopic info <topic>` to check whether your robots are accidentally subscribing to the same `/cmd_vel` topic.

**Comment by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on 2016-08-01**:
Thank you very much for your comment but everything seems to be fine, from the rostopic list i get both /robot1/cmd_vel and /robot2/cmd_vel. and from rostopic info i get both publishers /robot1/pubvel and /robot2/pubvel. Naturally, rqt_graph also shows this. I still get the same cmd_vel for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you do not properly initalize the random number generator with a seed. See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/ for an explanation.
You do have the `srand` call in there already, but commented out. Thus, this program will always produce the same "random" values.

Depending on how you start the `pubvel` node, you should probably initialize them differently. See e.g. [this stackoverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand) on how to initialize it differently.

Or you could use the [Boost Random Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) which afaik doesn't have this problems.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hugo Sardinha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27228/hugo-sardinha/) on 2016-08-02**:
Thank you very much mig. the stackoverflow discussion was where I found the answer to my problem. The reason why I had srand commented was because when it wasn't it still didn't work. I had to both have it outside the while loop and initialize it  like suggested in the discussion.

Thank you!